# Git warning about file change even if the file is being ignored?

Tags: git

For example, if I want  to change a branch `git checkout testing` (from `dev`), I'll get this warning:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        app/src/api/server.js
```

But as you can see, the file is being ignored:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: But (a) I *can't* see that the file is being ignored, and (b) clearly, it's *not* being ignored. (If the right hand pane of your image is meant to show the contents of `.gitignore`, note that a file that is actually in the index is tracked, regardless of whether it appears in `.gitignore`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the file was being tracked before so you need to explicitly remove it once, by this command:

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

This is related to this topic: [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: Do I need to do git commit after the code you provided me?

Comment: Yes. If you want to see the effect immediately you need to commit.

Comment: @alex could you please close this question by accepting the answer? (if the answer worked! :) )

Comment: is the file supposed to have its own version between branches? or the file will be the same for all branches?

Comment: It will have several versions among branches. So I guess you need to remove it from all branches. or remove it once in a commit and then merge that commit in all branches.